# Image Viewer with Survey

Tags: image-viewer, survey

I have a series of images that I would like to be manually reviewed for their quality and ease of collecting data.

For each image, I would like to ask a series of questions (similar to the example in the image below) and collect this information (ideally with the ability to export to .csv format):

Ideal Survey Format:
[image]

Data Output:

[image]

I initially reviewed surveymonkey which has the ability to add images as questions/ answers, but this would require a "new survey" for each image. My next step was to custom build a platform in R shiny/ OpenCV, but I was hoping there is already an easier solution available.

**Is there software that has this set up in place?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this solution by using [Qualtrics](https://www.qualtrics.com/) ["loop & merge"](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/block-options/loop-and-merge/).

**STEP 1:**
You first have to create a "block" for the image. In which you can put the following code in as a text field: `${lm://Field/1}`

**STEP 2:**
Then once the block is set  block you can click "Loop & Merge" on the left hand side:
[image]

**STEP 3:**
From there you can input images saved into the Qualtrics graphic library using the image location: `"<img src="example_url_link_data"/>"`

[image]

**STEP 4:**
Add your questions to a second block. To ensure all the questions stay on the same page, change the question setting to "single page".

Resources used:

- [YouTube Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Hru8H68po8&ab_channel=YiZhang)
- [Qualtrics Community Answer from older question](https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/12668/present-images-using-loop-merge)

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit

You could give [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) a try. PollUnit offers various ways to vote on images. You will find some examples [here](https://pollunit.com/en/tutorials/vote_for_images).

To get a survey in your format you can create a [PollUnit Survey](https://pollunit.com/en/survey) and add a "Matrix / Scale" or "Query information" step. Here you can simply put an image in the description. This could look like the attached example:

[image: Example image survey step]

Then you can create a step per image.
PollUnit is free for a limited amount of participants. CSV export is only available from the business plan.